# jQuery (plug-in) fade in fade out slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, resources, slider

I am trying to build a jQuery slider.

This will fade in and fade out images that are "stuck" in the same place.
(Is this explanation clear).

A little bit like this:

http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/377_slider/slider_sourcefiles/slider.html

But without the horizontal moving.

Can you point me to something similar, so I can modify it to my purpose but still don't have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: That page "without the horizontal moving" is just two images and some text. Is it perhaps for `jQuery.innerFade` you are looking?

Comment: @bzlm It would be something like the jQuery.innerfade with a list of images but what makes it change the transparency is no time but the movement of the slider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/9zqbY/

Using the jQueryUI slider widget, you should be able to implement this pretty easily.  My demo is far from perfect, but it should be enough to get you on the right track.  With the jQueryUI slider, you can bind a function to the `slidechange` event to fade your images in and out.  Here's a sample of that function:

```
$('#slider').bind("slidechange", function(event, ui) {
   var newIndex = $("#slider").slider("value");
   var oldIndex = $('#sliderContent .item').index('.shown');
   if (newIndex != oldIndex) {
       $('.shown').fadeOut().removeClass('shown');
       $('#sliderContent .item').eq(newIndex).fadeIn().addClass('shown');
   }
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: That is even too much! LOL (just kidding) Thank you very much that is actually perfect!

Comment: I will have to work in the smoothness part now, THANKS again!